# Windows Photo Viewer takes a lot of time to open pictures

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, windows-10, lag, windows-photo-gallery

I don't know why but after upgrading OS form Win 8.1 to win 10 Windows Photo viewer takes atleast 2-3 minutes to open a picture. Other applications open in no time. I don't why is it so what can I do to remove this problem ?

Comment: do you mean the desktop viewer or the photo app?

Comment: Windows Photo viewer

Comment: try IrfanView which I like much more: http://www.irfanview.com/